# Nesting an "SQL SELECT STATEMENT" as/inside the REGEX operator

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table called `People` with columns `PersonID` and `Name` and I can select a Person's Name like:

```
SELECT Name FROM People WHERE PersonID = 1
```

which for this example will return *'John'*.

I also have another table called `ForumPosts` with the fields `ForumPostID` and `PostContent` where PostContent is just `TEXT` which for the purpose of this example can be something like `"My Name is John"` or `"John likes football"`

Now I want to perform a Query which based on a given initial PersonID will return all rows from ForumPosts where the Person's Name matches a word contained in the PostContent field.

A regex which will match single words (or in this case the person's name) is:

```
[[:<:]]*Person'sNameHere*[[:>:]]
```

So ideally I want my SQL logic to be something like:

```
Select * FROM ForumPosts WHERE PostContent 
REGEX [[:<:]](SELECT Name FROM People WHERE PersonID = '1') [[:>:]]
```

However I am not sure if this is even possible or how I would structure the query.

Comment: Do be aware that what you are trying to do, here, will not scale very well... a query with `REGEXP`/`RLIKE`, just like the normal `LIKE` operator (which has an exception in one case that doesn't matter here), will require the server to read and compare the data of *every row*, *every time* you run the query, getting slower as your data grows.  These operators can't be optimized with an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a regex dynamically.  Regexes are just strings in MySQL, so you can just use `CONCAT` to create the string you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM ForumPosts
WHERE PostContent
    REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',(SELECT Name FROM People WHERE PersonID = '1'),'[[:>:]]')
```

Even better, you can use a JOIN instead of a subquery

```
SELECT ForumPosts.*
FROM ForumPosts
JOIN People ON PersonID = 1
WHERE PostContent REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',People.Name,'[[:>:]]')
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40828/1

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this logic using an `exists` subquery.  If I understand your logic correctly:

```
select fp.*
from ForumPosts fp
where exists (select 1
              from people p
              where personid = '1' and
                    fp.PostContent regex concat('[[:<:]]', name, '[[:>:]]')
             )
```